# OpenVPN - What's my IP Address

Tags: openvpn

I have OpenVPN running on a RaspberryPi on my network.  I setup my iPhone to to connect to my VPN when on the cell network.  When I go to WhatIsMyIP.com it still shows me that I'm coming from AT&T's network.  Should this be saying I'm coming from my own network since the request should be routed through the VPN?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware which is not topical for serverfaul http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5586/are-raspberrypis-ever-on-topic-for-serverfault refers.

Comment: It's about OpenVPN which is not hardware.

Comment: It's about a raspberry Pi which is a toy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, only traffic destined for the VPN network will be routed over the VPN.  To force all traffic over the VPN, use the `redirect-gateway` option in your config.

http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect